# Format float while printing dict

Tags: python, string, formatting, f-string

Is there any possibility to easily format float like this:

```
f"{value: .2f}"
```

while printing dict, that contains those floats as values? This doesn't work, but I'm looking for something equivalent:

```
f"{dictionary: .2f}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the keys of the dictionary to print each value (or combine them into one string to print).
You can loop on each key with :

```
for key in dictio.keys():
   print (key, "{:.2f}".format(dictio[key]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to print the value inside a dict while iterating over it. If this is the case this should do what you are trying to do :

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print("{:.2f}".format(value))
```